# Web3js: How to check the progress sendSignedTransaction()?

Tags: web3js

Im using a job queue for the transactions. I need to know progress to inform the users the status of their transaction. I've just tweak this code https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/1151#issuecomment-362002768

```
handleGetData = async (payload) => {
    try {
      const {
        token_symbol, address_from, address_to, amount, private_key_from,
      } = payload;

      const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(process.env.WEB3_PROVIDER));

      const tokenSelected = selectToken(token_symbol);

      const contract = web3.eth.Contract(tokenSelected.abi, tokenSelected.address, {
        from: address_from,
      });

      let bal = await contract.methods.balanceOf(address_from).call();

      console.log(`Balance before send: ${typeof bal === 'object' ? JSON.stringify(bal.balance) : bal} \n----------`);

      // const count = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(address_from);

      const amountToWei = web3.utils.toWei(amount);

      const rawTransaction = {
        from: address_from,
        // nonce: `0x${count.toString(16)}`,
        gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(gasPriceGwei * 1e9),
        gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(gasLimit),
        to: tokenSelected.address,
        value: 0,
        data: contract.methods.transfer(address_to, amountToWei).encodeABI(),
        chainId: +process.env.TX_CHAIN_ID,
      };

      const privKey = Buffer.from(private_key_from, 'hex');

      const tx = new Tx(rawTransaction);
      tx.sign(privKey);

      const serializedTx = tx.serialize();

      console.log(`Attempting to send signed tx:  ${serializedTx.toString('hex')}\n----------`);

      const receipt = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(`0x${serializedTx.toString('hex')}`);

      console.log(`Receipt info: \n${JSON.stringify(receipt, null, '\t')}\n----------`);

      bal = await contract.methods.balanceOf(address_from).call();

      console.log(`Balance after send: ${typeof bal === 'object' ? JSON.stringify(bal.balance) : bal}`);

      this.done();
    } catch (error) {
      this.job.failed().error(error.message);
    }
  };
```

I'm using redis kue for queueing. Thank you.

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: @goodvibration I edited my question and my code. Thank you

Comment: Side note: don't use `gasPriceGwei * 1e9`. Javascript's max safe integer will possibly be smaller. You may simply do `${gasPriceGwei}e9` surrounded by upper commas (the one on the top-left corner of your keyboard, which I am unable to depict here). And you don't need the `web3.utils.toHex` of course.

Comment: In any case, [here is a coding example from the official documentation](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html?highlight=sendTransaction#id71) for how you can track the status of a transaction. Check the one under `using the event emitter`. It allows you to wait for the hash, then for the receipt, then for each one of 24 confirmation events. Please note that this is relevant for web3.js v1.x, but it should be pretty similar to that of web3.js v0.x in case you're currently on this version.

Comment: (Upper-commas => "backticks" (i.e. `\``). You can include them in Stack Exchange's comments markdown by using an escape backslash before the character.)